# React: adding functional component onclick on state change

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to have a functional component called after a state change. The state includes a map, and the template iterates over the map. When an element is clicked, I want the state to change and call another functional component which fires an AJAX event.
This is the code in my primary component:

```
const [parentItems, setParentItems] = useState(null);
useEffect(() => {
     //ajax that gets bundles and returns "result", then:
     setParentItems(result);
}, []);
const loadItem = useCallback(item => {
    const pItems = parentItems;
    item.childItemsClicked = true;
    pItems.set(item.id, item);
    setParentItems(pItems);
}, [parentItems]);
const Item = props => {
    if (props.item.childItemsClicked) {
      return <ChildComponentItem item={props.item} />;
    } else {
      return <div />;
    }
};
```

Then in the return JSX:

```
{[...parentItems.keys()].map(itemKey => (
    <Element onClick={() => loadItem(parentItems.get(itemKey))}>
        <Item item={parentItems.get(itemKey)} />
    </Element>
))}
```

The child element, when called, makes an AJAX call, but I don't see that replacement happening. Does anyone know a way to make this happen?
It also doesn't have to be written this way; I'm just trying to find a way to use a functional component to make an AJAX call and populate results after one element in an iteration is clicked.

ETA: wrapped the loadItem function into useCallback()

Comment: Have you tried to wrap the `loadItem` function with [React.useCallback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback)?

Comment: I did try, looks like it didn't make a difference. I edited my question to include this.